# If $p \mid m^p+n^p$ prove $p^2 \mid m^p+n^p$

Tags: prime-numbers

Prove that for a prime $p>2$, if $p \mid m^p+n^p$, prove $p^2\mid m^p+n^p$

From Fermats theorem I concluded $p \mid m+n$, so $p^2\mid (m+n)^p$. How do I proceed next? Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: Take p=2, m=3, n=5. Clearly $2|(3^2 + 5^2)$, but 4 does not divide 34. Did you mean odd prime?

Comment: Oops sorry $p>2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, you can generalize:

> If $d$ is odd, and $d\mid m+n$ then $d^2\mid m^d+n^d$.

**Proof:**

Let $k$ be such that $n = dk-m$. Then $$m^d + n^d = m^d+(dk-m)^d = \sum_{i=1}^d \binom d i (dk)^i(-m)^{d-i} \equiv \binom d 1 (dk)^1(-m)^{d-1}\pmod {d^2}$$

But $\binom d 1 = d$, so this means $d^2\mid m^d+n^d$.

Your particular problem follows since if $p\mid m^p+n^p$ then $p\mid m+n$.

Even more generally:

> If $D$ is odd and $d\mid \gcd(D,m+n)$ then $d^2\mid m^D+n^D$.

Comment: Great!! Thanks, but the summation should be till $d$, not $\infty$ right??

Comment: Yep. Infinity doesn't really hurt, since $\binom d j=0$ when $j>d$, but I meant $d$. :)

Answer (score 9):

Since you know that $p^2 \mid (m+n)^p$, you need to see that $p^2 \mid \left((m+n)^p - m^p - n^p\right)$. So look at

$$(m+n)^p - m^p - n^p = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}m^{p-k}n^k.$$

You know that each of the binomial coefficients is a multiple of $p$. And you know that $n \equiv -m \pmod{p}$, so

$$(m+n)^p - m^p - n^p \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} (-1)^k m^p \pmod{p^2}.$$

Now the symmetry of the binomial coefficients helps.

Comment: I didn't get the mod $p^2$ part..

Comment: If $a\equiv b \pmod{p}$, and $p\mid c$, then $p^2\mid c(a-b)$, so $ca\equiv cb \pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: yup thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that $p\mid C_p^k$ for $0<k<p$

Comment: Technically, you only really need that to show that $p\mid m+n$, which he has already concluded otherwise.