# For a prime $p$ such that $p | x^p - y^p$, prove that $p^2 | x^p - y^p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have tried using FLT but I didn't really go anywhere from there. The first obvious observation that $x \equiv y\pmod{p}$, and that $x^{p(p+1)} \equiv y^{p(p+1)}\pmod{p^2}$. A hint would be great because I am definitely missing something obvious.

Comment: $x=kp+y$ then using binomial formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu how would i know that it is specifically divisible by $p^2$? could you please elaborate a bit? using the result from $p|x-y$ and binomial theorem, as you said, i've gotten an equation for $x^p - y^p$ but i don't know how to proceed (apologies for the earlier ping)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $a^p-b^p$ is divisible by $p$, then it is also divisible by $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192458/prove-that-if-ap-bp-is-divisible-by-p-then-it-is-also-divisible-by-p2) - found through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5Cmid%20x%5Ep-y%5Ep%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2%5Cmid%20x%5Ep-y%5Ep%24&p=1), with there being other very similar or duplicate questions, e.g., [Show $a^p \equiv b^p \mod p^2$](/q/1580630).

Comment: $(kp+y)^p-y^p={p\choose p} k^p p^p+\ldots+{p\choose 2}k^2p^2 y^{p-2}+{p\choose 1}kp y^{p-1}+y^p-y^p$. All summands before $y^p$ are divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: ah, i missed the $p$ factor in the $kp$ that makes it divisible. thanks for the help Ivan.